# css targeting specific p tags

Tags: html, css

I asked a similar question earlier but I found a better way to word it. So, given an html document that has multiple div ids, and each div id with several p tags inside it..like,

```
<div id="testing">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <p>this is number one</p>
    <p> this is number two </p>
</div>
<div id="testingTwo">
    <h2>hello again! </h2>
    <p> i just want this one </p>
```

How would I specifically target the second p tag of the id 'testing' without affected the first p tag of the second id 'testingTwo'?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `nth-of-type` selector to select second `p` element.

By using `#testing` in the selector, you're only targeting the elements that are inside of the `#testing` element. So, you don't have to worry about the `p` elements elsewhere.

```css
#testing p:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="testing">
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <p>this is number one</p>
  <p>this is number two</p>
</div>

<div id="testingTwo">
  <h2>hello again! </h2>
  <p>i just want this one</p>
```

As an alternative, you can also use `#testing :nth-child(3)` to select third child element inside `#testing` element. However, this is not a reliable method since the markup may change and this will not work.

```css
#testing :nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="testing">
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <p>this is number one</p>
  <p>this is number two</p>
</div>

<div id="testingTwo">
  <h2>hello again! </h2>
  <p>i just want this one</p>
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
#testing :nth-child(3) {
   //code
 }
```

Use '#' if targeting an ID, and '.' if a class.

Comment: This will not work, use `p:nth-child(3)` otherwise first `p` will be selected

Comment: Now this will also not work, you need a space between `#testing` and `:nth...`. See http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/55prtq2g/

Comment: No, you fixed it by adding space, try removing `p`, it'll still work. Also, it looks like this selector selects the third `p` elements, but that's not true, it just selects the third child. It's _confusing_. Check http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/55prtq2g/1/

Answer (score 1):

For perhaps the simplest method, you could give the P tag you want a new ID or class to set it apart.

```
  <div id="testing">
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <p>this is number one</p>
  <p id="mytarget"> this is number two </p>
  </div>
```

Then target that ID.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do too, but my assignment says that I cannot alter the html file :\

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-of-type(n)` css property.Here n is int value starts from 1...n.

Solution for your problem:

```
#testing p:nth-of-type(1) {
  font-size:18px;
}
```

Codepen demo : [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdMWaW)

Refer [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can target specific p-tags by calling the div id and the nth child inside the p tag you want to alter, for example

```
     #testing :nth-child(3) {
        color: red;
     }
```

would call the third p-tag inside the  testing.